ValueError: One of the requested xi is out of bounds in dimension 0
I am trying to interpolate a 48 x 86 grid that has wind speed data (the grid being time x height) to a 71 x 81 grid (also time x height). I am trying to use the interpn function from scipy.interpolate because from what I've read, it is the recommended function for interpolating regular grids. When i attempt use of this function, I get the title error (ValueError: One of the requested xi is out of bounds in dimension 0)
I have tried using the following:
This block of code represents the grid I want to interpolate my data onto.
rangeTime = np.arange(np.datetime64('2018-05-30T00:20:00'),np.datetime64('2018-05-31T00:00:00'),np.timedelta64(20,'m'))
rangeHeight = np.arange(200,4250,50)
rangeTime = rangeTime.astype("float64")
inTime, inHeight = np.meshgrid(rangeTime,rangeHeight,indexing='ij')

This is the data I want interpolated, and its dimensions are represented by:
times= ds.time.values #1d time array
heightvalues = ds.heights.values #48 x 86 grid with height data
height1d = heightvalues[0,:] #only need 1st slice, so I get 1d array with all my heights.
wspeed = ds.wspd.values #wind speed data, 48 x 86 grid

And finally I use the interpn function like so:
grid_wspeed = interpn((times,height1d),wspeed,(inTime,inHeight), method = 'linear')

I was expecting my wind speed data to be in a 71 x 81 grid. I don't understand why I'm getting the ValueError. Thank you in advance for helping me.

The error is saying that one of the values in inTime or inHeight is outside of the range of points you've given it (i.e. not within the bounds of times1 or height1d), which would be extrapolation. You haven't provided a reproducible example so I don't know what the values are and cannot help you more than that.

Would you recommend using a different function to interpolate my data? I'm not sure how I'd create a reproduceable example. I'll try to make one.

As far as I understand, you want to perform a 2D interpolation of data, on a regular grid, to achieve upscaling (or also possibly downscaling).
Since your data are regularly distributed, I suggest the use of scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.
Here is an example in 2D (time x space), where my data z would correspond to your wind velocities.
Imports
from itertools import product

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

Generate fake sample data on a regular grid
# 2D grid (time, x)
t_min, t_max = 0, 1
x_min, x_max = -1.5, 1.5

time = np.linspace(t_min, t_max, 50)
x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100)

time_grid, x_grid = np.meshgrid(time, x, indexing="ij")


# function to generate random z data
def func(x, y):
    return x * (1 - x) * np.cos(4 * np.pi * x) * np.sin(4 * np.pi * y**2) ** 2


# z data to interpolate
z = func(time_grid, x_grid)

Showing what the raw data that we want to interpolate look like
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.imshow(z.T, origin="lower", extent=[t_min, t_max, x_min, x_max], aspect="auto")

ax.set_xlabel("time")
ax.set_ylabel("x")

plt.show()


Performing the regular interpolation
"""NB: since the interpolation is made on a regular grid,
RegularGridInterpolator do not need the redondant meshgrid version of time and
x. It only requires the 1D arrays of time and x, in upgoing order. However z
data obviously must consist in a multidimensional grid.
"""
func_interp = RegularGridInterpolator((time, x), z)

# number of pixels that we want after upscaling or downscaling
n_time, n_x = 100, 200

time_upscaled = np.linspace(t_min, t_max, n_time)
x_upscaled = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, n_x)

# `func_interp` works with a "1D array" of points (each point being itself a
# "1D array" of coordinates). itertools.product is a fast way to generate the
# list of points present in a multidimensional grid.
points_upscaled = np.array(list(product(time_upscaled, x_upscaled)))

# we compute the corresponding z-value at each point
z_upscaled = func_interp(points_upscaled)

Plotting the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# z_upscaled being a 1D array of values, it must be reshaped into a grid
ax.imshow(
    z_upscaled.reshape(n_time, n_x).T,
    origin="lower",
    extent=[t_min, t_max, x_min, x_max],
    aspect="auto",
)

ax.set_xlabel("time")
ax.set_ylabel("x")

plt.show()



Note that interpn() just wraps RegularGridInterpolator() if method = 'linear', so if interpn() doesn't work, then RegularGridInterpolator() likely won't work either.

I tried applying your example with my data, but when I try to upscale my windspeed data to the desired grid, i get the same ValueError.
